# What is the best way of calling an Azure Logic App endpoint from Python?

Tags: python, azure, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to find a proper way of calling Azure Logic App endpoints from Python. I know that it is possible to call the url using `requests` package, but I am just curious if there is a specific python client library available for this purpose?
I already came across `LogicManagementClient` but it seems it's more of an Azure Resource Management client and it is really complicated to figure out how to call a Logic App endpoint through it.

Comment: what's wrong w/using requests, don't you literally just need to hit the endpoint?

Comment: @Chris there's no problem w/using requests. I just wanted to make sure that they haven't released any official python client for azure logic apps

Comment: @A23149577, as far as I know, no there are no client library released. The reason behind is that logic app HTTP trigger is basically like any other regular HTTP endpoint

Comment: @theabodeofcode Yes, but there are some params such as `sig` which is basically the endpoint signature. I wasn't sure if this value should be generated on-the-fly or just hard-coded inside request params. It seems Logic App first verifies this value from coming requests and I don't feel comfortable having it hardcoded in my code ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define `sig` in  your code with rest api. Also there is a logic app management api for python:[azure.mgmt.logic](https://pypi.org/project/azure-mgmt-logic/).

And there is a run method under `workflow_triggers_operations`. You could use it to run a workflow trigger. Here is the  method detail [run(resource_group_name, workflow_name, trigger_name, custom_headers=None, raw=False, **operation_config)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-logic/azure.mgmt.logic.operations.workflowtriggersoperations?view=azure-python#run-resource-group-name--workflow-name--trigger-name--custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config-).

Comment: I believe this is the most secure way of doing this.